# Select parttition to install Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: partition, software-installation

[image]I need a confirmation.

I want to install Lubuntu 18.04 on part2 partition .

Here is my environment. [image: partion table]

sda1 is Lubuntu 17.04.

sda3  is 20.04 broken.

sda4 is 20.04.

I want to install 18.04 on sda3.

If I  take the something else option during installation I am presented with a partition table.

If I select sda3 I presume it will be installed there but it is not clear .

Then , (from memory) it says something about root? grub?? . I stopped there as I know I have a good grub .[image: start up] and I dont want to loose my boot options.

I had installed 20.10 and it only offered 20.10 at boot so if it crashed I would have been stuffed so I took it off.

I want to install 18.04 as even with 20.04 apps that run under snap are very slow . I may be at the limit of hardware for 20.04 [image: hardware]

All advice greatly received.

Comment: Please only use current versions. Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) so Lubuntu 18.04 is not current. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours What brand/model system? You are using old BIOS/MBR configuration which is for systems over 10 years old. Version of grub installed to MBR will be last install. But that grub can offer to boot all installs if os-prober is on. Better with multiple installs to turn os-prober off and use 40_custom. Only use Something Else install option.

Comment: and BTW do you really need 93GB of swap?